# How do I restrict access to my apis to specific cognito userGroups in cdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I have two user groups that are use very generic user pool client

```
const userPoolClient = new UserPoolClient(this, "UserPoolClient", {
      userPoolClientName: "UserPoolClient",
      userPool,
      generateSecret: false,
      authFlows: {
        userPassword: true,
        userSrp: true,
      },
      oAuth: {
        flows: {
          authorizationCodeGrant: true,
        },
        scopes: [OAuthScope.EMAIL, OAuthScope.OPENID]
      },
    });

    new CfnUserPoolGroup(this, "PremiumGroup", {
      groupName: "Premium",
      userPoolId: userPool.userPoolId,
    });

    new CfnUserPoolGroup(this, "GuestGroup", {
      groupName: "Guest",
      userPoolId: userPool.userPoolId,
    });
```

I'd like to make it so that only users from the 'premium' user group are allowed to access certain api endpoints. for example I have an 'deleteCustomerMetaData' endpoint only premium users should be able to call:

```
const apiKey = new ApiKey(this, "ApiKey", {
      apiKeyName: "DMPSApiKey",
      description: "Api for DMPS Mining",
    });

    const deleteResourceResource = api.root.addResource(
      "deleteCustomerMetaData"
    );

    deleteResourceResource.addMethod(
      "DELETE",
      new LambdaIntegration(userDeleteData),
      { apiKeyRequired: true}
    );
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly restrict access by Cognito groups. Instead you need to check manually the client's user group from the request token either within a Lambda Authorizer or directly in each of your API Lambdas. Here is AWS's own documentation for an example of a [Lambda Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html).